# getting Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR while inserting a dynamic values using node js and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to insert the dynamic field values to mysql database using node js.  In my server console am getting this error:

```
{ [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'[object Object]'f2a06305-7e98-4462-9ba2-72ce85fa4d32','undefined',
'59a3ff90-aa4a' at line 1]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 
}
```

What does the error mean and how do I resolve it?  Below is the server code:

```
var mysql=require('mysql');
var http=require('http');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var path=require('path');
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.json());       
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
var myconnection = mysql.createConnection({
host : "localhost",

user : "root",

password : "",

database : "siva"
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + ""));
var uqid= uuid.v1();
var it_id=uuid.v4();
var tt=1;
var status="active";

   app.post("/insert",function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
        /* TODO: Now just check that your drive function is correct, SQL is correct and whether what arguements passed to SQL callback is correct */
        myconnection.query('Insert into cate_tbl (`cat_id`,`cat_name`,`cat_desc`,`cat_view_count`,`cat_status`) VALUES ("'+uqid+'","'+req.body.cat_name+'","'+req.body.cat_desc+'","'+tt+'","'+status+'")',function(err, results, fields) {
            //if (err) throw err;
            if (err){
                console.log("DB Error"+err); 
                res.send("add cate_tbl failed"+err);
            }else {
             generateQuery = function(data,tableName){
    var fields = Object.keys(data);

    var values = [];
    for(var o in data) {
        values.push(data[o]);
    }
    return "Insert into "+tableName+"("+fields.join("cat_it_id,cat_it_name,cat_pid,cat_it_count,cat_it_desc,cat_it_status")+") values ("+values.join("'"+it_id+"','"+req.body.item_name+"','"+uqid+"','"+req.body.tem_count+"','"+req.body.item_desc+"','"+status+"'")+")"
}

var query = generateQuery(req.body,"cate_item");

myconnection.query(query,function(err, results, fields) {
    //your logic.

     if(err)
      {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else
        {
          res.end(JSON.stringify(fields));
        }

 });
            }
        });
    });

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("It's Started on PORT 3000");
})
```

Comment: @EricLeschinski do you know whats the error is

Comment: Yes, but big dumps of code like this, and a: "Please point at my syntax error" are not helpful artifacts for stackoverflow.  So I'll try to help you solve the problem yourself.  Can you add to the question the exact interpreted SQL statement passed to your 'myconnection'?  When you give us the SQL that is being run, your syntax error will be obvious.  You can print it out by first putting it into a variable, printing it to log, then copy/pasting it here.

Comment: @EricLeschinski solved the problem myself thanks for sparing time Merry Christmas

Comment: Can you posted the correct code?

Comment: can you post the correct code @M Balajivaishnav